# C# Ler arquivo TXT e deletar

Tags: c#

Boa Tarde, estou desenvolvendo um programa que lê um certo arquivo (contém mais de 60k de linhas) remove uso desnecessários e organiza e grava em outro arquivo.

```
using (StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(lerArquivo))
{
    while (!leitor.EndOfStream)
    {
        var linha = new ArquivoTxt();
        linha.Linha = leitor.ReadLine();
        conteudoArquivo.Add(linha);
    }

    var gravarArquivo = @"C:\log\meutxt.txt";

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(gravarArquivo))
    {
        conteudoArquivo = conteudoArquivo.Where(_ => _.Linha.StartsWith("|") &&
                                                     _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|0" &&
                                                     _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|-" &&
                                                     _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|C" &&
                                                     _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|I" &&
                                                     _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "| " &&
                                                     _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|R" &&
                                                     _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|D" &&
                                                     _.Linha.Substring(0, 2) != "|E").ToList();

        foreach (var item in conteudoArquivo)
        {
            string[] linha = item.Linha.Split('|');
            string ordemVenda = linha[1].Trim();
            sw.WriteLine(linha[1]);
        }

        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

só que no retorno ele só me retorna a 1ª coluna do Arquivo e eu queria o retorno da Linha inteira

Comment: não é pq você está lendo apenas a `linha[1]` ??

Comment: E por que usa o `using` e fecha o arquivo? E existe algum motivo para criar variável onde não precisa e deixar de criar onde será muito útil?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu já tentei mudar não retorna oque eu quero

Comment: @Maniero eu estou iniciando, ainda não sei muito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim não consegue o que pretende?

```
string[] caracteresAceites = new string[] { "|0", "|-", "|C", "|I", "| ", "|R", "|D", "|E" };

using (StreamReader leitor = new StreamReader(lerArquivo))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\log\meutxt.txt"))
    {
        while (!leitor.EndOfStream)
        {
            string linha = leitor.ReadLine();

            if(linha.StartsWith("|") && !caracteresAceites.Contains(linha.Substring(0, 2)))
            {
                string[] _linha = linha.Split('|');

                if(_linha.Length > 1)
                    sw.WriteLine(_linha[1].Trim());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Dei uma "otimizada" no seu código*

Não precisa do `sw.Close()` porque o `using` já faz isso (e o `Dispose` do objeto).

Comment: Que bela otimizada em :D, estou começando na programação, obrigado pela ótima otimizada e claro deixando o código mais fácil de se entender

Comment: Não resolve o seu problema? Obrigado :)

Comment: não consegui, no caso ele me retorna somente a 1 coluna Ordem de Venda, oque eu queria que ele me retornasse a linha do bloco de notas inteira, porém ele ta quebrando a linha e limpando tudo que vem depois do |Ordem de Venda|

Answer (score 2):

Troque:

```
sw.WriteLine(linha[1]);
```

para:

```
sw.WriteLine(item.Linha);
```

Comment: rapaz! obrigado eu troquei (linha[1]) por (item.Linha), e consegui oque eu esperava.